# Best hashing method before saving password into database table for django

Tags: python, database, django, hash, passwords

```
def register(request):
    flag = True
    possible = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    token = ''

    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

    user = UsersModelForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userf = UsersModelForm(request.POST)
        username = userf.data['username']
        password = userf.data['password']
        passwordrepeat = userf.data['passwordrepeat']
        email = userf.data['email']

        if password != passwordrepeat:
            flag = False
            passVariable = {'user':user, 'flag': False}
            return render_to_response('register.html', passVariable, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        elif password == passwordrepeat:
            for i in range(1,10):
                temp = random.choice(possible)
                token = token + temp

            print token
            if userf.is_valid():
                check = userf.save(commit=False)
                check.email_token = token
                check.email_token_expiry = current_datetime + timedelta(1)
                check.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('register.html', {"user": user, 'flag': True}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I need to apply hashing method for `userf.data['password']` and `userf.data['repeatpassword']` before saving into database table.

Which hashing method is preferable for hashing using python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`bcrypt`](http://code.google.com/p/py-bcrypt/).

Here's an example taken from the [README](http://code.google.com/p/py-bcrypt/source/browse/README):

```
import bcrypt

# Hash a password for the first time
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())

# gensalt's log_rounds parameter determines the complexity
# the work factor is 2**log_rounds, and the default is 12
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt(10))

# Check that an unencrypted password matches one that has
# previously been hashed
if bcrypt.hashpw(plaintext, hashed) == hashed:
    print "It matches"
else:
    print "It does not match"
```

Comment: Can you post code how to use that bcrypt? That would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an explanation about how this is done for `django.contrib.auth` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#how-django-stores-passwords). For detailed information, you can also take a look at the `make_password` function in the [hashers module](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py).